# CSS display:inline prevents element from refreshing

Tags: javascript, html, css, inline

I have a clock in my projet inserted in a div and it's really important to me that it is rendered "inline". 
Indeed, the AM/PM cell is right next to it and I'd like it to move as clock gets shorter (ie. 11:11 instead of 22:22).

So i set its property to display: inline; like this :

```
.time{
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 50pt;    
}
```

The same goes for the am/pm element :

```
.ampm{
    display: inline;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    font-size: 18pt;
    top: -40px;
}
```

This is the HTML file :

```
<div class="timeDate">
    <div class="hour"><div id="time" class="time"></div><div id="ampm" class="ampm"></div></div>
    <div id="date" class="date"></div>
</div>
```

and at least, the Javascript piece of code that keeps update it:

```
setInterval('checkTime()', 1000);

function checkTime(){
    currentTime = new Date();
    _minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    _hours = currentTime.getHours();
    _day = currentTime.getDay();
    _date = currentTime.getDate();
    _month = currentTime.getMonth();
    time.innerHTML = _hours + ":" + _minutes;
    ampm.innerHTML = ampmValue;
}
```

It works fine with display: block;
Plus, when i add seconds I can see it updates, but only like, 2 times out of 10.
Do you have an idea of why, and how could I fix that ?
Thanks in advance !

Here is a link to my project (Chrome ONLY) : http://acemond.free.fr/FEZAcetheme/BETA/FEZ_Lockscreen_1.2-3.theme/LockBackground.html
It's meant to work locally so load the page entierly, then reload (you'll keep cache)

Hmm ok... Kinda found a way out...

```
if(mode12h) time.innerHTML = _hours + ":" + _minutes + "<sup><font size='5'>" + ampmValue + "</font></sup>";
else time.innerHTML = _hours + ":" + _minutes;
```

It seems simple but the issue with that piece of code is that the .click function assignated to the clock wouldn't work fine any more.
So I added an empty control that is above all this in order to receive the clicks.
It works, no idea why.

**EDIT**: found an even BETTER way to do that:

```
hours.innerHTML = _hours + ":" + _minutes + "<span class='ampm'>" + ampmValue + "</span>";
```

with associated CSS:

```
.ampm{
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    height: 75px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 40spx;
    font-size: 20pt;    
}
```

I did this before, but it prvented the .click function to work correcty just as i said. But now it works well with the panel i added above that manages the click.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be as simple as adding:

```
var time = document.getElementById('time');

var ampm = document.getElementById('ampm')`
```

before doing

```
time.innerHTML = _hours + ":" + _minutes;
ampm.innerHTML = ampmValue;
```

Comment: I should have put it in the description, the clock updates fine with display: block. So I don't think it comes from the Javascript

Comment: I think I'm going to use an alternative: set the text in the same div with a <sup> flag...

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this code works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/3xyYh/1/

```
setInterval(checkTime, 1000);
```

Removed the quotes around the checkTime call but maybe that's not the problem either? However this is working fine for me with display: inline.

Comment: Try to add seconds and see the result, they won't ALL appear.

Comment: The two elements must be relative.

Comment: Also seconds works fine for me: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/3xyYh/2/) but maybe there is more styling that makes it not showing up correctly?

Comment: ok just check this : http://acemond.free.fr/FEZAcetheme/BETA/FEZ_Lockscreen_1.2-3.theme/LockBackground.html
Give it one sec, free's slow...
It's not meant to work on anything else than Chrome/iPhone

See ? some seconds are missing, and I have no idea why :(

Comment: I guess it's just saturated, right ? It laggs as soon as it's on something else -_-

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I found an another way to do that exactly the way i needed to and with "inline"
Yeah i saw the "float" thing but it doesn't put AMPM inline with the hours

Answer (score 0):

You should apply the `display: inline;` to your parent element `.timeDate`

**Edit:**
Okay! I've seen your clock, and I found something on that is: You should give float to your element. See below:

```
.ampm {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    float: right;
    font-size: 18pt;
    margin-top: 0;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 20px;
    right: 2px;
}

.time {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    font-size: 45pt;
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: Well both "time" and "ampm" are into "hour", I don't want hour to be displayed inline with others, I want AMPM to be displayed inline with "time"

Comment: Do you want ampm to go to next line?

Comment: see my edited answer that are both inline and working as what you want